# Which approach of sharing template and logic is preferred in VUE?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, inheritance, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two **unrelated context** components which share logic and template in a way that looks like one is extending the other.

Imagine Drop and Pick components like this:

```js
// pick.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class Pick extends Vue {
  template: '<p>{{name}}</p>',
  created() {
    console.log('Hello Pick');
  }
  data: { 
    name: 'pick',
    count: 0
  },
  methods: {
    add: function () {
      this.count++;
    }
  }
}

// drop.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class Drop extends Vue {
  template: '<p>{{name}}</p> <span v-if="isUserFriendly">Greetings!!!</span>',
  created() {
    console.log('Hello Drop');
  }
  data: { 
    name: 'drop',
    isUserFriendly: false,
    count: 0,
    drops: 0
  },
  methods: {
    add: function () {
      this.count++;
      this.drops++;
    },
    remove: function () {
      this.count--;
    },
  }
}
```

Intuitively, one can say Drop is extending Pick while adding some functionality and alter the template. This seems to be a good solution but then I thought to myself that to achieve that Pick template should look like this:

```html
<p>{{name}}</p> 
<span v-if="isUserFriendly">Greetings!!!</span>
```

Remember that I said **unrelated context** components?
Now Pick needs to know about isUserFriendly which is unacceptable nor I think its the right solution. Moreover it will create overhead in the future as inheritance can be hard to maintain (imagine more components to extend and logic to share).

What do you think will be the best approach here? Maybe there is another way around which Im not familiar with?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component composition is a common way to do this. Drop component contains a superset of functionality, i.e. pick component should allow to be wrapped in a way that will allow for desired output and behaviour.

For parent-child relationship, data pieces are passed as props and events, and view pieces are passed as slots.

Additional logic stays in parent component.

In child component (`Pick`):

```
<div>
  <p>{{name}}</p>
  <slot name="extraText"/>
</div>
```

and

```
add: function () {
  this.count++;
  this.$emit('add');
}
```

In parent component (`Drop`):

```
<Pick @add="drops++">
  <template v-slot:extraText>
    <span>Greetings!!!</span>
  </template>
</Pick>
```

Comment: I really like this approach!
What if add() will be completely different as DROP contains another implementation of add() which is non related to Pick implementation. I dont want for example now this.count++ to be called

Comment: Then probably a child component should be more simple implementation, both Pick and Drop will extend its functionality.